# How to make this code of slider work for many sliders on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use this code to show not only just one slider but many dynamic sliders  .see pic [image]

this code just work for one slider

here is my code :

https://jsfiddle.net/4e13bmvu/

```
    <div id="le_le_slider" class="le_le_slider">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="items" class="items">
      <span class="le_slide">le_slide 1</span>
      <span class="le_slide">le_slide 2</span>
      <span class="le_slide">le_slide 3</span>
      <span class="le_slide">le_slide 4</span>
      <span class="le_slide">le_slide 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a id="prev" class="control prev"></a>
  <a id="next" class="control next"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to change id  to class and then code by using loop.

Comment: could you please show me how :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSFiddle code you've created:
HTML has

```
<div id="le_le_slider" class="le_le_slider">
```

and Javascript points to it with 'getElementById'

```
var le_le_slider = document.getElementById('le_le_slider'),
```

Each slider needs it's own ID on the HTML page _ and to be controlled in the Javascript with the same ID

I cannot find any documentation online for the slider that you are using_ to point you to the instructions for how to code multiple LeLeSliders _

If this is the case then you should consider using a different slider which has the documentation connected to it that will help you create more than one slider _ Perhaps Slick Slider would suit your needs better >> https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

This link goes to a Codepen example of multiple Slick sliders in action on the same page >> https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/bWRZzB

Comment: Slick is a much more common slider @GiveawayRobot _ So it's likely that you'll find more answers on Stack Overflow for any issues you have _ Thanks for accepting my answer : ) Good Luck!